# Multiprocessing throwing Runtime Error after executing p.start()

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, runtime-error, python-multiprocessing

I am getting a Runtime Error after my code executes the p.start() method of Multiprocessing package in python.

Error which gets logged is as follows:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/anujpanchal/Documents/exportify-micro-booking/functionality/Notifications.py",
> line 396, in send_notification
> p.start()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py",
> line 121, in start
> self._popen = self._Popen(self)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/context.py",
> line 224, in _Popen
> return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)   File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/context.py",
> line 284, in _Popen
> return Popen(process_obj)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py",
> line 32, in **init**
> super().**init**(process_obj)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py",
> line 19, in **init**
> self._launch(process_obj)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/popen_spawn_posix.py",
> line 42, in _launch
> prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/spawn.py",
> line 154, in get_preparation_data
> _check_not_importing_main()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/spawn.py",
> line 134, in _check_not_importing_main
> raise RuntimeError(''' RuntimeError:
> An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
> current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.
>
> ```
>     This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
>     child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
>     in the main module:
>
>         if __name__ == '__main__':
>             freeze_support()
>             ...
>
>     The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
>     is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
> ```
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    File
> "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/spawn.py",
> line 116, in spawn_main
> exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/spawn.py",
> line 125, in _main
> prepare(preparation_data)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/spawn.py",
> line 236, in prepare
> _fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/spawn.py",
> line 287, in _fixup_main_from_path
> main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py",
> line 268, in run_path
> return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py",
> line 97, in _run_module_code
> _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py",
> line 87, in _run_code
> exec(code, run_globals)   File "/Users/anujpanchal/Documents/exportify-micro-booking/functionality/Notifications.py",
> line 513, in 
> Notifications(checkpoint="discharged_on_transshipment").send_notification(booking_id="XPF100283",
> tracking_obj=tracking_obj, scraper_update=False)   File
> "/Users/anujpanchal/Documents/exportify-micro-booking/functionality/Notifications.py",
> line 470, in send_notification
> return response.errorResponse("Some error occurred please try again!")   File
> "/Users/anujpanchal/Documents/exportify-micro-booking/functionality/response.py",
> line 50, in errorResponse
> return jsonify(response), status   File "/Users/anujpanchal/Documents/exportify-micro-booking/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/json/**init**.py",
> line 339, in jsonify
> if current_app.config['JSONIFY_PRETTYPRINT_REGULAR'] or current_app.debug:   File
> "/Users/anujpanchal/Documents/exportify-micro-booking/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py",
> line 348, in **getattr**
> return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)   File "/Users/anujpanchal/Documents/exportify-micro-booking/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py",
> line 307, in _get_current_object
> return self.__local()   File "/Users/anujpanchal/Documents/exportify-micro-booking/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/globals.py",
> line 51, in _find_app
> raise RuntimeError(_app_ctx_err_msg) RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
>
> This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that
> needed to interface with the current application object in some way.
> To solve this, set up an application context with app.app_context().
> See the documentation for more information.

Why such a type of Runtime Error is being throwed, is it because I updated my MacBook to Big Sur 11.3 or is it because of something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know too much about the Mac. In general, I believe most versions use (or used to use) OS call `fork` to create new processes. This meant that you did not have to put code that creates new processes within a block such as ...

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

... which is required for platforms that use OS call `spawn` to create new processes, the reason being that when `spawn` is used the new process is created by initializing a new address space, launching a new Python interpreter and re-running the code from the very top of the program re-executing an code at global scope. This would result in re-executing in a recursive loop *ad infinitum* the very code that created the new process if that code were not conditionally executed by the above `if` statement.

It would seem that in your update to Big Sur 11.3 the new default method of creating new processes has switched from `fork` to `spawn` -- and probably for a good reason. So I hesitate to suggest that you first try calling ...

```py
multiprocessig.set_start_method('fork')
```

... to restore `fork` as the default method to use for creating new processes.

**Instead, I would suggest that you enclose your process-creation code in the aforementioned `if` block. It's really unfortunate that you decided not to post any of your code or else I could have showed you exactly how to do that.**

Answer (score 1):

I had hit the same issue when running the below code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import Value

def worker(sema, pool, resource):
    name = mp.current_process().name
    print("{}: Making pool active".format(name))
    with sema:
        pool.make_active(name)
        print("{}: Waiting for 1 second".format(name))
        time.sleep(1)
        print("{}: Modifying resource".format(name))
        resource.value = resource.value + 1
        print("{}: Making pool inactive".format(name))
        pool.make_inactive(name)

class ActivePool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ActivePool, self).__init__()
        self.manager = mp.Manager()
        self.active = self.manager.list()
        self.lock = mp.Lock()

    def make_active(self, name):
        with self.lock:
            self.active.append(name)

    def make_inactive(self, name):
        with self.lock:
            self.active.remove(name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mp.set_start_method('fork')
    pool = ActivePool()
    sema = mp.Semaphore(3)

    resource = Value('d', 10.0)

    procs = []
    for i in range(20):
        proc_name = "process_{}".format(i)
        p = mp.Process(target=worker, args=(sema, pool, resource,), name=proc_name)
        procs.append(p)

    for p in procs:
        p.start()

    for p in procs:
        p.join()

    print("Value of resource after modification: {}".format(resource.value))
```

The above code worked after adding the following inside the if loop:

```
multiprocessig.set_start_method('fork')
```